# btrfs snapper layout configuration or installation

Tags: system-installation, configuration, btrfs, snapshot, rsnapshot

I've installed 23.04 with btrfs and I have now 2 subvolume:
@
@home

May I install snapper now or should I create more subvolume?
and eventualy how? is there and howto?

Kindly Regards